# What are the limiations of windows server web edition?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Trying to get a handle of the differences between windows server 2008 r2 and the web edition.

I'm using it for a website, so IIS7 and sql server express.

The application is asp.net mvc.

What exactly do I gain with going with standard edition over web?

Comment: PDF warning: Microsoft publishes an [Edition comparison guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/6/FC6006B5-866E-42C1-88F8-9AC4B8BC610D/WS%20Brand%20Pages%20-%20Editions%20Comparison%20Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[15 key-presses and 9 mouse clicks](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/6/FC6006B5-866E-42C1-88F8-9AC4B8BC610D/WS%20Brand%20Pages%20-%20Editions%20Comparison%20Guide.pdf) - must try harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems This link will help 
http://server-extra.com/difference-between-windows-server-2008-editions-web-datacenter-standard-and-enterprise-versions/

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.